# Incorrect derivation of geometric series

Tags: fake-proofs, geometric-series

So this is something really really simple but for some reason I honestly cannot figure out why this is wrong.

I was deriving the equation of the summation of a geometric series to the nth term because I hate memorizing.

So this is what I did: 
Let

$S = a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ... + ar^n $
where a is some constant

First I subrated $a*r^n$. Getting:

(A)

$S - ar^n = a + ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^{n-1}$

Then,

(B)

$S - a = ar + ar^2 +ar^3 + ... + ar^n $

Those seemed reasonable, so then I divided equation B by r

(B_1)

$(S - a) / r = (ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^n) / r $

So that,

$ (S / r) - (a / r) = a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ... ar^{n-1}$

Via distribution of (1/r)

Now we are and equality between A and B_1. Therefore:

(C)

$S - ar^n = (S/r) - (a/r) $

Which also seems reasonable. Then move both S terms and ar^n:

(C_1)

$S - (S/r) = ar^n - (a/r) $

Then factor out S:

(C_2)

$S (1 - (1/r)) = a(r^n - (1/r)) $

Finally divide:

(C_3)

$S = a(r^n - (1/r)) / (1 - (1/r)) $

Then I multiplied the right side by (-r/-r):

(F)

$S = a(1 - r^(n+1)) / (1 - r) $

as our final equation.

Of course the correct equation is: 
(CORRECT)

$S = a(1 - r^n) / (1 - r) $

if you try $S_{mine }= S_{correct}$, you eventually show that 1 = 0. Which is incorrect.

I understand the usual derivation of the equation, but it's bothering me that I can't see why this is wrong. 
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The "correct" equation is incorrect: that's the sum of $n$ terms, but starting from 0, so it ends at $n-1$. You are calculating the sum of $n+1$ terms, starting from 0 and ending at $n$. No wonder they are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. It is actually true that$$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^n=a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$$Congratulations!